# SQLAlchemy query for object with count of relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Lets say I have SQL Alchemy ORM classes:

```
class Session(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  user_agent = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

class Run(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

  session_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('session.id'))
  session = db.relationship('Session', backref=db.backref('runs', lazy='dynamic'))
```

And I want to query for essentially the following:

```
((session.id, session.user_agent, session.runs.count())
  for session in Session.query.order_by(Session.id.desc()))
```

However, this is clearly 1+n queries, which is terrible. What is the correct way to do this, with 1 query? In normal SQL, I would do this with something along the lines of:

```
SELECT session.id, session.user_agent, COUNT(row.id) FROM session
LEFT JOIN rows on session.id = rows.session_id
GROUP BY session.id ORDER BY session.id DESC
```

Comment: Have you looked at the ORM tutorial, specifically, the section labeled [Querying with Joins](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins)?

Comment: Yes, I did look at it, however it isn't clear to me how to do the join followed by the group and add a count to the final list of columns.

Answer (score 12):

Construct a subquery that groups and counts session ids from runs, and join to that in your final query.

```
sq = session.query(Run.session_id, func.count(Run.session_id).label('count')).group_by(Run.session_id).subquery()
result = session.query(Session, sq.c.count).join(sq, sq.c.session_id == Session.id).all()
```

Answer (score 8):

The targeted SQL could be produced simply with:

```
db.session.query(Session, func.count(Run.id)).\
    outerjoin(Run).\
    group_by(Session.id).\
    order_by(Session.id.desc())
```